# Create an automated script that login in into netflix

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'd like to make an automated script in python using selenium that log in here: https://www.netflix.com/Login.
I've tried with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/Login")
while True:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ui-text-input[name = 'email']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','test1')", element)
    element2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ui-text-input[name = 'password']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','test1')", element2)
    driver.refresh()
```

But it raises an error occurred in this line of code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "netflixlogin.py", line 6, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ui-text-input[name = 'email']")
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 437, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 752, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"ui-text-input[name = 'email']"}
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpk_odq6d0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpk_odq6d0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpk_odq6d0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpk_odq6d0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpk_odq6d0/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

So there's a problem in this line of code:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ui-text-input[name = 'email']")
```

Maybe a wrong syntax? I start using selenium recently so I am still not very good

UPDATED SCRIPT with not errors but it doesn't still work:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/Login")
while True:
    element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form.login-form input[name=email]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','test1')", element)
    element2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("form.login-form input[name=password]")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','test1')", element2)
    driver.refresh()
```

SOLVED. WORKING SCRIPT:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/it/")
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".authLinks.signupBasicHeader")
login.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
element.send_keys("test1@gmail.com")
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.login-button.btn-submit.btn-small")
submit.click()
element2 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
element2.send_keys("test1")
submit2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.login-button.btn-submit.btn-small")
submit2.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the `ui-text-input[name = 'email']` selector is not going to match anything on this page since there is no `<ui-text-input>` element on the page, but there is an `input` with `ui-text-input` class. Fix your selector:

```
form.login-form input[name=email]
```

By the way, instead, of `while True` approach, use the [built into selenium mechanism to wait for specific conditions to happen on a page](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits).

And, should not you be choosing the login type (email/phone) first?

Comment: ok thanks now it doesn't show any error, but it doesn't write email test1 and password test1 at all with the command: driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','test1')", element)

Answer (score 0):

I think below is syntax for CSS selector in selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ui-text-input[name = 'email']"))
```

Answer (score -1):

Solved.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.netflix.com/it/")
login = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".authLinks.signupBasicHeader")
login.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_name("email")
element.send_keys("test1@gmail.com")
submit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.login-button.btn-submit.btn-small")
submit.click()
element2 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
element2.send_keys("test1")
submit2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".btn.login-button.btn-submit.btn-small")
submit2.click()
```